# Created an API SOAP

Tags: php, api, soap

I'm new to SOAP and my aim is to develop an API to communicate with a Client. So the client will send me an xml with this kind of structure :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
        <GetInfoResponse xmlns="namespace">
           <GetInfoResult>
                <data1></data1>
                <data2></data2>
          </GetInfoResult>
        </GetInfoResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to parse data1, data2 and do some process with them and then return a response with again a specific envelope.

Here is my API :

```html
<?php
    class server
    {
        public function GetInfo()
        {
            //process
        }
    }

    try
    {
        $server = new SoapServer(null, array("uri" => "http://uri"));
        $server->setClass("server");
        $server->handle();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "erreur : ".$e;
    }
?>
```

In order to try my API I have simulated the client side :

```html
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient(null,
    array(
        "location" => "http://project/server.php",
        "uri" => "http://uri",
        "trace" => 1
    ));

    try
    {
        echo $client->__soapCall("GetInfo", array());
    }
    catch(SoapFault $e)
    {
        echo $e;
    }

?>
```

Now my issue is to send an xml as a parameter to my $client in order to process it in the server side.

Do anyone has a solution for it ?